# Symfony2, add additional parameters to the route sent by the form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, routes

I would like to retrieve the parameters sent by the form (method="get") and add them to the route.

This is the **route**:

```
frontend_list:
path:     /travels/{page}
defaults: { _controller: ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list, page: 1 }
```

and this is the **form**:

```
          <form action="" method="get" class="form_sort" id="myForm">
             <span class="manage_title">Sort by:</span>
                <select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="sort" onChange="sendForm();">
                        <option value="">-------</option>
                        <option value="country:asc">Country A-Z</option>
                        <option value="country:desc">Country Z-A</option>
                        <option value="destination:asc">City A-Z</option>
                        <option value="destination:desc">City Z-A</option>
                 </select>
           </form>
```

and this is the **controller**:

```
    public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $nbByPage = $this->container->getParameter('travel.number_by_page');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {

        $sort = $request->query->get('sort');
        list($orderBy, $orderWay) = explode(":", $sort); //explode 

        $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend($nbByPage, $page, $orderBy, $orderWay);

        return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
            'listTravels' => $listTravels,
            'page'     => $page,
            'nb_page'  => ceil(count($listTravels) / $nbByPage) ?: 1
        ));
    }

    $orderBy = "id"; // set default orderBy
    $orderWay = "desc"; // set default orderWay

    $listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend($nbByPage, $page, $orderBy, $orderWay);

    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
        'listTravels' => $listTravels,
        'page'     => $page,
        'nb_page'  => ceil(count($listTravels) / $nbByPage) ?: 1
    ));
}
```

So I'd like to have url like this for example when select a choice "sort" :

```
localhost/agence/web/app_dev.php/travels?orderby=country&orderway=aesc
```

Right now , I get an nonfunctional url like this when select a choice:

```
localhost/agence/web/app_dev.php/voyages?sort=country%3Aasc
```

So my question is how to add those parameters in the route **frontend_list**  and add them to the path in twig view beside parameter **page** to have a correct url with **pagination**:

```
                        {% if nb_page > 1 %}
                            {% if  page == 1 %}
                        <a class="link_prev">Previous</a>
                            {% else %}
                        <a href="{{ path('frontend_list', {'page': page - 1}) }}" class="link_prev">Previous</a>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% if  page == nb_page %}
                        <a class="link_next">Next</a>
                            {% else %}
                        <a href="{{ path('frontend_list', {'page': page + 1}) }}" class="link_next">Next</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good way to create a sortable list, not in symfony.

I suggest you take a look at [**KnpPaginatorBundle**](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) - SEO friendly Symfony2 paginator to sort and paginate.

But, if you need to use code written above. I suggest you do the second select, separate to choose ASC / DESC.

Comment: thank you, I'd like to ask you can I make a form with select list to sort data by name desc or price for example with KnpPaginatorBundle ?

Comment: See answer below, I could not put it in the comments - it is too long.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible, after the installation bundle you must override at the firstly template "**KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination: sortable_link.html.twig**". Because the default template is for link, you should create new one for select option. To do this, create in your project structure "**app/Resources/KnpPaginatorBundle/views/Pagination/sortable_option.html.twig**"

```
<option {% for attr, value in options %} {{ attr }}="{{ value }}"{% endfor %}>{{ title }}</option>
```

Now your code will require small modifications:

```
<form action="" method="get" class="form_sort" id="myForm">
    <span class="manage_title">Sort by:</span>
        <select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="sort" onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country', 'object.countryProperty', {'direction': 'asc'}) }}
            {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country', 'object.countryProperty', {'direction': 'desc'}) }}
            {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'City', 'object.cityProperty', {'direction': 'asc'}) }}
            {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'City', 'object.cityProperty', {'direction': 'desc'}) }}
        </select>
</form>
```

## EDIT:

And of course You have to change the path in the configuration file

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_option.html.twig # sort option template
        #sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template (default)
```

Comment: I got this error `ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "KnpPaginatorBundle" from namespace "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle" in D:\wamp\www\agence\app\AppKernel.php line 28. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?`

Comment: appKernel: `new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),`

components are in **vendor\knp-components** and bundle is in **vendor\bundles\knp\BundlePaginatorBundle**

Comment: You need to download this via composer. [link](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#installation-and-configuration)
Here you have the bundle installation instructions in the project.

Comment: yes I have download them via `git clone git://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components.git vendor/knp-components` 
and `git clone git://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle.git vendor/bundles/Knp/Bundle/PaginatorBundle`

Comment: What version of Symfony do You use?

Comment: "Deps (for Symfony2.0) and composer.json (for Symfony2.1+) files are used for installing third parties (vendors) and also core files of Symfony" **You must use composer.phar"**

`{
    "require": {
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4"
    }
}`

Comment: Yes I did this `"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        .....................
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4"
    }`

Comment: Now run in console `php composer.phar update knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65593/discussion-between-pawel-kolanowski-and-hous).

Comment: @hous Please "tick" the right answer if your problem is resolved now.

Comment: I got some errors `[RuntimeException] 
Failed to clone git@github.com:KnpLabs/knp-components.git, git was not foun 
d, check that it is installed and in your PATH env`

`update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] 
[--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with- 
dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platfor 
m-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN] `